# Pass data to loop in meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a template in meteor that contains a loop.  `{{text}}` is what I'm looping over.  `{{id}}` is from the template context and is not accessible within the loop.  How do I pass `{{id}}` into the data context of the loop?

```
<template name="label>
    {{#each label_set}}
        {{text}} {{id}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `id` is in the parent context, you can access it from within the `each` by using `../` like so:

```html
<template name="label">
  {{#each label_set}}
    {{text}} {{../id}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Also see: [A Guide to Meteor Templates & Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/).